# Call js code on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here I have a code and when I click on button I must add div ID new to div ID bottom but I dont know where I wrong:

```
contentStr += '<button class="dodaj">Add to timeline</button></div>';

$(".dodaj").click(function() {
  $('#bottom').append($('<div id="new">'+place.name+'</div>').css('marginLeft',100));
});

$(contentStr).dialog({ modal:true });
```

SO first I call contentStr in modal window jquery UI and in this modal window I must call button with class .dodaj and into ID bottom to add div ID new

So what is wrong here?

Comment: Since the button is added dynamically, You need delegation like `$(document).on('click','.dodaj', function (){`

Comment: With append you shoud append a string or a DOM element, but not a jquery object. If you want to change its CSS afterwards, you should use .appendTo: `$('<div id="new">'+place.name+'</div>').appendTo('#bottom').css('marginLeft',100);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

As your `button` is added dynamically so it is not accessible directly ,So you have to use `Event delegation`.

```
$(document).on("click", ".dodaj", function () {
    $('#bottom').append($('<div id="new">' + place.name + '</div>').css('marginLeft', 100));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this for dynamically added elements, bind it to the closest static parent element

```
$(document).on('click', '.dodaj', function () {
    $('#bottom').append($('<div id="new">' + place.name + '</div>').css('marginLeft', 100));
});
```

Comment: I dont know why dont work

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

`$('<div id="new">'+place.name+'</div>')` must be the problem.

if you really have a `<div id="new">` in your page, you should get it with `$("#new")`

I think what you want is to remove de $() and set the margin properties inline:

```
append('<div id="new" style="margin-left:100;">content</div>')
```